# In Python, I am trying to obtain fusion of two images, but I am getting unexpected result

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

I am trying to fuse two images using Kekres wavelet transform in python.

I have used DFT (size 32*32) as base matrix to generate wavelet matrix (size 1024*1024). Same program is written in MATLAB, it shows fused result correctly.

But this python program is not showing fused image. I am not able to understand the reason. Sample images are here

MR Image 
[image: MR iamge]

Registered CT Image
[image: Registered CT image]

Expected Fused Image
[image: Expected fused image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from WaveletMatrix import GenerateWaveletMatrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp

def dftmatrix(N):
    return sp.fft(sp.eye(N))

TranformSize=32
WaveletSize= TranformSize*TranformSize       
dftm=dftmatrix(TranformSize);  
WaveletMat=GenerateWaveletMatrix(dftm,TranformSize)

FixedImageR = cv2.imread('D:\MyTransforms_HP\DataSet3\MR_LumbarSpineT2Cube00001.jpg',0)
MovingImageR = cv2.imread('D:\MyTransforms_HP\DataSet3\R.jpg',0)
SizeFixedImage=FixedImageR.shape
SizeMovingImage=MovingImageR.shape

if SizeFixedImage!=SizeMovingImage:
    print("Images must be of same size")
    exit()

FixedImageR=FixedImageR.astype(np.double)
MovingImageR=MovingImageR.astype(np.double)    
FixedImage = cv2.resize(FixedImageR,(WaveletSize,WaveletSize),0,0)
MovingImage= cv2.resize(MovingImageR,(WaveletSize,WaveletSize),0,0)
FixedImage=np.ceil(FixedImage)
MovingImage=np.ceil(MovingImage)

#WaveletImage1= np.zeros(shape=(WaveletSize,WaveletSize),dtype=np.double)
#WaveletImage2= np.zeros(shape=(WaveletSize,WaveletSize),dtype=np.double)

WaveletT=WaveletMat.T
WaveletImage1=np.zeros(shape=(WaveletSize,WaveletSize),dtype=np.complex)
WaveletImage2=np.zeros(shape=(WaveletSize,WaveletSize),dtype=np.complex)

WaveletImage1=WaveletMat.dot(FixedImage).dot(WaveletT)
WaveletImage2=WaveletMat.dot(MovingImage).dot(WaveletT)


plt.figure(1)
plt.imshow(np.uint8(WaveletImage1),cmap='gray')
plt.show()

plt.figure(2)
plt.imshow(np.uint8(WaveletImage2),cmap='gray')
plt.show()


FusedImage1=np.zeros(shape=(WaveletSize,WaveletSize),dtype=np.complex)

FusedImage1=(WaveletImage1 + WaveletImage2) / 2

newimg=np.zeros(shape=(WaveletSize,WaveletSize),dtype=np.complex)
mainD=np.zeros(shape=(WaveletSize))


mainD[0:TranformSize]=WaveletSize
mainD[TranformSize:WaveletSize]=TranformSize

for i in range(0,WaveletSize):
    for j in range(0,WaveletSize):
        newimg[i,j]=(FusedImage1[i,j]/(mainD[i]*mainD[j]))


inverseMAT=(WaveletMat.T).dot(newimg).dot(WaveletMat)

plt.figure(3)
plt.imshow(np.uint8(inverseMAT),cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you sure the values are correct? Because I do get 8079 + 0j.

Comment: WaveletImage1[0,0]
Out[75]: (5467+0j)

WaveletImage2[0,0]
Out[76]: (10691+0j)

(WaveletImage1[0,0]+WaveletImage2[0,0])/2
Out[77]: (8079+0j)

Comment: I get correct value on console when i check it for only one value of the matrix..however when i run a loop for entire image , i m getting those weird values

Comment: And if you use average or mean from numpy?

Comment: How big is the dataset? Could you provide a small sample?

Comment: If `FusedImage, WaveletImage1` and `WaveletImage2` were numpy arrays, I would suggest the vectorized form `FusedImage = (WaveletImage1 + WaveletImage2)/2`

Comment: i have edited the question..pls see

Comment: i found that the unexpected result is because of WaveletImage1=WaveletMat.dot(FixedImage).dot(WaveletT)
WaveletImage2=WaveletMat.dot(MovingImage).dot(WaveletT) ..and inverseMAT=(WaveletMat.T).dot(newimg).dot(WaveletMat)...these three lines..why matrix multiplication in python gives different result than matlab and octave?